# How can I copy multiple files over scp in one command?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have to transport a lot of files from one PC to another (both Linux). I would like to use `scp` for that, but `scp` only allows for transferring one file at a time.

How can I do this?

I have

- No possibility to use rsync or any other protocol
- No possibility to use passphrase-free certificates (but have a certificate with a passphrase)
- A list of files to transfer and a list with the destination path of the files on the other server
- The files are spread out over a lot of directories, and not all the files in the directories I want to copy

If possible, I would like to gzip and ungzip transparently to save bandwidth!

Is this possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`tar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/files.html):

```
tar cvzf - -T list_of_filenames | ssh hostname tar xzf -
```

Comment: Heres the file format:
"In c mode, tar will read names to be archived from filename.  The special name ``-C'' on a line
             by itself will cause the current directory to be changed to the directory specified on the following line.  Names are terminated by newlines unless --null is specified.  Note
             that --null also disables the special handling of lines containing ``-C''."

Answer (score 21):

> I would like to use scp for that, but scp only allows for transferring one file at a time.

I'm pretty sure that isn't true, at least not for the `scp` command provided by the OpenSSH included with most Linux distributions.

I use `scp file1 file2 ... fileN user@host:/destination/directory/` fairly frequently.

For transparent compression, the SSH protocol has this built in and `scp` can use it if you provide the `-C` option on the command line. For lots of similar small files you will find the tar+gz option suggested by akira gains better compression as it can make use of similarity between such files where `scp` compresses each file as a separate entity. I generally prefer to use scp though as it is easier to resume a partial transfer (or, though I know in this situation the questioner doesn't have the option) `rsync` as that is both even easier to resume and shares the tar+gz option's whole-stream compression advantage.

Comment: This is the right answer, but it really only transfers one file at a time. Nevertheless it will make full use of available bandwidth and should run as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't `scp -r yourdir otherhost:/otherdir` work?

Try this then:

```
tar cfz - . | ssh otherhost "cd /mydir; tar xvzf -"
```

the `z`-flag to tar does compression. Or you can use -C to ssh:

```
tar cf - . | ssh -C otherhost "cd /mydir; tar xvf -"
```

Comment: what does `-C` do?

Comment: The problem is, I have a list of files. The files are spread out over a lot of directories, and not all the files in the directories I want to copy

Comment: @Nathan: -C is to lett ssh do the compression.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL5, here is the only way possible that I know of to secure copy a list of files that contain special characters (like a space). Make a shell script and include the following:

```
FILE="/path/filename"
while read line; do
scp "$line" username@servername:/destination/
done < $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually supply a list of files to `scp` with the following protocol,

```
scp <user>@<host>:{<file1>,<file2>,...,<fileN>} <destination>
```

Note that the file list is wrapper in French braces.

Bonus: If you want to copy a select list of files from the *same* directory, use,

```
scp <user>@<host>:<source>{<file1>,<file2>,...,<fileN>} <destination>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done w/o much trouble.

I simply create a list of files with the hostname next to each file and scp seems to parse it fine. ie.

```
srchost=`hostname`
myfiles="${srchost}:~/.bashrc ${srchost}:~/.bash_profile ${srchost}:~/.vimrc ${srchost}:~/.viminfo ${srchost}:~/.toprc ${srchost}:~/.dir_colors"
scp -v $myfiles $HOME
```

Scp seems to work fine with this syntax. As I attempted it without the hostname next to each file it failed after the first file. I seem to recall another syntax I used for this before and will post it once I locate it.

Comment: This works, but is quite slow - it seems to start a connection for each file... (I came here looking for a solution for the slow copy...)

`~/` can mostly be left out - SCP operates relative to the home directory...

If you have a list from elsewhere in `$list`: `scp $(echo "$list"|sed "s/^/$srchost:/") local_destination` (This will break for filenames with spaces though)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to parts use a command like this to create an archive from your file list

tar -cvf allfiles.tar -L mylist.txt

Then use scp to download the archive.

scp user@remotehost:~/allfiles.tar

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files